# Does empty have a gradable antonym in English?

Tags: antonyms

Empty doesn't seem to have a gradable antonym. If something is *not empty* and *not full*, then it is **not empty**, but is there a single word expression for this?

### Edit:

To make it more evident, I'm looking for something like what *warm* is on the scale of *cold* and *hot*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an antonym of empty *is* full.

Comment: Not really. There is a space inbetween. The glass does not get full if I put a little water in it, so it is `not empty` and `not full` at the same time.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the opposite of "empty" is "full."  If something is less than full--and hence, not empty--it is half-full, one-quarter full, two-thirds full, almost empty, etc.  So, no, there does not appear to be one word that describes the phenomenon of something's being between empty and full, except maybe the word "when," as in "Let me pour you some coffee.  Say when."  (She starts to fill up your cup, at which point you say) "When!"

Comment: I see there is a tendency to down vote if someone has a different understanding of something, or just asks something he knows some answer for. I feel this is a valid question, maybe needs some other wording. `Antonym` maybe was not a good choice. Whatever. I feel it rude to neglect an opinion without conversation. @rhetorician thank you for the insightful explanation.

Comment: Of course if a glass has some water, it cannot be empty or full. There is *some* water. In other words; there is a certain quantity, a measure, it is partially filled, it is neither full nor empty, there is a portion... etc.

Comment: You could simply use [nonempty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonempty) but that doesn't necessarily exclude "full" of course.

Comment: @allprog you can always edit your question if you realize that it will be misinterpreted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA down voting does not help if done by guts and not driven by rational reasoning. Editing doesn't help these people. Actually, editing could be done by these people. This is life. I'm not a native English speaker but still dare to ask in this forum. What I get is denial by guts feelings. Quite discouraging. Nevertheless, I think it's impossible to misinterpret this question if someone takes the time to read the `two lines of content` below the title, but I added one more line to make sure.

Comment: I have had more than my fair share of down votes, and 99% were anonymous. Count yourself lucky if someone has pointed out a mistake. I agree it is harsh to down-vote a question without first asking for clarification but it happens all the time, and not only to non-native speakers!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have my vote on others' and usually try to compensate for these anonym "Captain America"s. I'm not saying you should do the same but it's more encouraging. :)

Comment: If something is *not empty,* then it is *partly full*. I don't think there's any one-word synonym for *non-empty* and *partly full*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sparse* and its antonym *dense* may serve in some contexts, such as mathematics and computer science. For example, a sparse set is a set that has few members out of a large potential population of members. An empty set has no members, and a dense set has many members. However, I can't recall hearing the term *full set* in this context.

In other contexts, such as "a glass half-full" one would not use *sparse* or *dense*.

Comment: Could you provide a link which backs up your claim that "dense" is the antonym of sparse in the context of mathamatics?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on sparse matrices states "a sparse matrix is a matrix populated primarily with zeros (Stoer & Bulirsch 2002, p. 619) as elements of the table. By contrast, if a larger number of elements differ from zero, then it is common to refer to the matrix as a dense matrix." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix.

Comment: The Judy IV Shop Manual - which documents a programming library for storage of word or string indexes - states " hashing is essentially a way of converting sparse, possibly multi-word indexes (such as strings) into dense array indexes". See http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/shop_interm.pdf, page 9.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include that link and quote in your answer. The best answers are usually self-contained.

Answer (score 5):

The word 'antonym' needs defining before one can comment sensibly on this sort of question. There are different but related senses.

At http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/antonymsterms.htm , one class of antonyms is termed:

**... Gradable Antonyms**

and defined:

> Gradable antonyms include pairs like the following: beautiful - ugly
>   expensive - cheap fast - slow hot - cold increase - decrease long -
>   short love - hate rich - poor sweet - sour wide- narrow These pairs
>   are called gradable antonyms because they do not represent [refer to]
>   an either-or relation but rather a more-less relation. The words can
>   be viewed as terms at the end-points of a continuum or gradient.

Now while *empty* and *full* are essentially absolute adjectives, whereas say *fast* and *slow* are not, the former are **certainly** terms which refer to 'the end-points of a continuum or gradient'. They are gradable antonyms.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. So you derived that "warm" can exist for "empty"-"full". But does it?